# Dataflow job hang by Can't find ext4 filesystem in beam 2.14

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My dataflow job is hang and I found the error as below

```
2019-08-27 22:09:42.030 HKT
EXT4-fs (sdb): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Expand all | Collapse all {
 insertId:  "s=be15be46dadc4bf6b53cb72a83412a3f;i=4b3;b=655c37b5c26541178d67bd3a584d0256;m=1b4b156;t=59119d2e5aba9;x=c15bd8bf26ae8753"  
 jsonPayload: {…}  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/projectname/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fsystem"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-08-27T14:09:49.701365316Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 timestamp:  "2019-08-27T14:09:42.030249Z"  
}
```

and other warning

```
W 2019-08-27T14:09:16.285720Z [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:12] Duplicate line for path "/var/run", ignoring. 
W 2019-08-27T14:09:16.299244Z Cannot set file attribute for '/var/log/journal', value=0x00800000, mask=0x00800000: Operation not supported 
W 2019-08-27T14:09:16.299660Z Cannot set file attribute for '/var/log/journal/32ffce3c053bcc2b3d6585166bd050d1', value=0x00800000, mask=0x00800000: Operation not supported 
W 2019-08-27T14:09:19.332660Z Could not load the device policy file. 
W 2019-08-27T14:09:22.434563Z [WARNING:persistent_integer.cc(96)] cannot open /var/lib/metrics/version.cycle for reading: No such file or directory 
W 2019-08-27T14:09:28.609260Z [CLOUDINIT] cc_write_files.py[WARNING]: Undecodable permissions None, assuming 420 
W 2019-08-27T14:09:28.610011Z [CLOUDINIT] cc_write_files.py[WARNING]: Undecodable permissions None, assuming 420 
W 2019-08-27T14:09:28.610490Z [CLOUDINIT] cc_write_files.py[WARNING]: Undecodable permissions None, assuming 420
```

Even though upgrade beam to 2.15.0, this issue still here.

**Update**

When I run the same code in anther GCP project, the pipeline could work well...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a GCE issue. You may need to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/).